# Generating constrained random numbers

Tags: reference-request, random-variables

I need to find a way to generate random vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n_v}$ and $w \in \mathcal{R}^{n_w}$ such that they satisfy the condition $$R_1 v + R_2 w = c,$$
where $R_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_c \times n_v}$ , $R_2\in \mathbb{R}^{n_c \times n_w}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n_c}$ are known. I assume that the equation is under-determined ($n_c < n_v+n_w$) and that the vectors $v$ and $w$ have known (possibly different) distributions, say $v$ is normal with zero mean and unity variance and $w$ is uniformly distributed in a hypercube.

Is there any way to generate such random numbers? I have been unable to find any relevant literature on this kind of problem.